# Time comparison with ActiveSupport failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
now = Time.zone.now
=> Wed, 19 Feb 2014 21:30:56 UTC +00:00 
Time.zone.at(now.to_i)
=> Wed, 19 Feb 2014 21:30:56 UTC +00:00 
now == Time.zone.at(now.to_i)
=> false
```

How is it possible?

**Upd:**

```
Time.zone.at(now.to_i).to_i == now.to_i
=> true
```

Comment: What about `now == Time.zone.at(now.to_f)`? Is that true?

Comment: Time is never equal, it varies at microseconds or even lesser units, you cannot determine which time is same, as you need to pause the world to do that :), for time based testing use [`Timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)

Comment: @bjhaid lol wat? I compare the same time because I build it from `now.to_i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby tracks time down to the nanosecond:

```
now = Time.zone.now
=> Wed, 19 Feb 2014 21:30:56 UTC +00:00 
Time.zone.at(now.to_f)
=> Wed, 19 Feb 2014 21:30:56 UTC +00:00 
now == Time.zone.at(now.to_f)
=> false
```

But if you compare the nanoseconds, you will see they are not the same, even when creating the time object using the float value, because the float value used to create the new time object is not as accurate as the nanosecond value of the time:

```
now.nsec
=> 956134961
Time.zone.at(now.to_f).nsec
=> 956134796
```

Comment: I see the difference in nanoseconds. But why does it exist if I not getting but build new time with `Time.zone.at(now.to_i)`?

Comment: @freemanoid Because when using `to_i`, it creates a new time without any nanoseconds: `Time.zone.at(now.to_i) # => 0` When using `to_f`, it is more accurate, but still doesn't match exactly, as you can see in my second code block.

Comment: Is there any chance to use `BigDecimal` for nanoseconds like `now.to_d`?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried using it, but it appears that you can only create a `BigDecimal` from a string, and I couldn't create a `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` object using a specific nanosecond value. I'm not sure if there is a way to do it somewhere out there, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Note: we've noticed that this behavior can vary. In OS X it looks like the